# Term Store -Set Hierarchy is not Shown in the Term Reuse Window

Tags: reusable

I am trying to perform a Term Reuse. I choose the term ,I right click and choose term reuse .I then get the Term Reuse window. so far so good. However, I only get the highest level of my term store set . I get only the set name but cannot drill down inside the set to choose the term to reuse.

In order to troubleshoot this, I created another term set ( there was only one set ) ,created some terms under it and tried to perform reuse on them - it did succeed! so the problem lies with the way that specific term set was created.

Can you advise?
Thanks
Gali

Comment: I have the same problem. Just for the record.